# Optimizing the website with .htaccess

Tags: php, optimization, .htaccess, compression, apache2

I've tried to optimize my website using YSlow for directions. However, even though I have added the `DEFLATE` code at **.htaccess** to gzip the files, YSlow still doesn't show the files as gzipped. I tried testing my website using this: http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php and it shows that my webpages are **not** gzipped or compressed. How else can I make them gzipped or compressed?

This is the .htaccess:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

################ Expires Control ################
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf)$">
# 2 weeks
ExpiresDefault A1209600
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html)$">
# 2 hours
ExpiresDefault A7200
Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
# 3 days
ExpiresDefault A259200
Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Apart from this, what else can I do to optimize the speed and reduce the loading time of my webpage?

Also, the image on the page keeps loading every time I refresh the page. How do I cache it to make it load quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to enable "mod_gzip"

Put this in your .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Comment: I tried that, and yet it shows that my files are not gzipped. I'm not sure what else do I have to do to gzip them.

Comment: To be sure: are you sure you've changed the .htaccess rules I provided? (because these are just example rules)

I think your web host might've disabled mod_gzip to safe some cpu cycles. ;-)

Comment: how else then can I compress my files, if my webhost has disabled mod_gzip? Any other alternatives?

Comment: It's ugly but you can use the PHP "ob_gzhandler" (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php) to compress all the requests. 

Little howto: http://www.ardamis.com/2010/07/11/compress-files-without-mod_gzip-or-mod_deflate/

Answer (score 0):

Hello Just Put Below code in htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch ".(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers

# BEGIN Turn ETags Off
FileETag None
# END Turn ETags Off
```